# Trying to add a "Like" count for a song with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Currently off the EmberJS wagon for now, and checking out AngularJS. I was trying to create a list of song titles with a "Like" link next to them. When you click on "Like" a count for the number of likes is listed next to the song title. Here's my jsfiddle and thanks for your help! http://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/SpQH5/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making your $scope.like function do this will work (http://jsfiddle.net/SpQH5/9/):

```
$scope.like = function (song) {
    song.like += 1;
};
```

Due to Angular's data-binding `{{song.like}}` is automatically updated in the DOM when `song.like` is incremented.

---

Note you can also accomplish this without a scope function by incrementing `song.like` in the `ng-click` directly like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpQH5/15/):

```
  <div class="song" ng-repeat="song in songs">
    <a href="#" ng-click="song.like = song.like + 1">like</a> ({{song.like}}) 
    <h3>{{song.title}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gloopy and Andy. I should have specified this, but how would I write the code to post this "like" to a specific song to a REST URL?